# Problema al acceder a mi docker desde un puerto del servidor anfitrion

Tags: servidor, docker, virtualización

tengo un TNAS (TerraMaster)  en el que estoy montando docker, es bastante facil (en teoria) porque tiene  su store y una itnerfaz grafica  nada mal.

Yo me creo mi docker y tal sin problemas le doy a correr y tira. Pero el roblema esta en que mi cuando intento acceder a los peurtos que le he puesto (Puerto local: 8585,  Puerto de red: 85, Tipo: tcp).

Una vez creado pues intento hacer lo logico: **urlmiservidor.loquesea:8585** y con esto me deberia de meter en el servidor pero que va. Me dice **no se puede conectar**.

Entonces este tema me tiene un poco perdido, pero no le veo mas historias de porque no funcion, mira que he monstado servidores a puto terminal con ubuntu server y cosas asi sin problemas, pero esto parece que cuanto mas facilidades mas se complica.

Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme. Animo con la cuarentena

Comment: Me imagino que habilitaste los puertos?

Comment: No, no he tocado nada, eso estuve buscando. En principio al ser un SO privado aunque basado en linux no sabia si tenia que hacer o se hacia solo. Y supongo que estamos hablando dentro del NAS no ? El ruter no tendrai sentido tocar los puertos no ?

Comment: Se me olvido mencionarte @Synay

Comment: Deberías partir por eso, abrir puertos por firewall (si es que tiene el SO)